# Different expectations during mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-stream, spock

I'm testing the filtering of my messages.
It will only save the message if the id does not exist yet.

```
List<Message> messages = ninitializedDto.stream()
        .filter(message -> !messageRepository.existsById(message.getId())
        .map(this::initializeMessage)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

return messageRepository.saveAll(messages);
```

But in my Spock test, the size always returns 1. (Even though I printed the `messages.size()` before the return (it returns 0)

```
def "createMessages should filter and save only messages that does not exist yet"() {
        given:
        UninitializedDto dto = Mock()
        dto.getId() >> 2L

        List<UninitializedDto> messageDtos = [dto]

        messageRepository.existsById(dto.getId()) >> true

        when:
        initialize.createMessages(messageDtos)

        then:
        1 * messageRepository.saveAll(_) >> {
            List<Message> savedMessageList ->
                assert savedMessageList.size() == 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There's a bug that wraps the list argument in another list.

```
1 * messageRepository.saveAll(_) >> {
    List<Message> savedMessageList ->
    List<Message> messageList = savedMessageList.get(0) as List<Message>

    assert savedMessageList.size() == 0
}
```

Comment: Why don't you fix the bug in your application instead of writing a test which proves that the bug is actually a bug, testifying the wrong behaviour by a passing test? Isn't one of the purposes of writing tests to uncover such problems and then to fix them?

Comment: @kriegaex the bug is Spock. not our application. hmm?

Comment: You mean the bug was in your test, right? Not in Spock itself. I think we misunderstood each other here.

Comment: @kriegaex the bug is Spock's. I believe. Since the expected input of the function `saveAll()` is a just `List<Message>` (JPA Repository), for some reason it wraps the List into another List. So the result of the Lambda becomes (for some reason) becomes `List<List<Message>>` I hope I explained it correctly. Appreciated your comment.

Comment: I still think that the bug is not in Spock. But I can hardly say anything intelligent about your class under test if you don't share it. If you refuse to edit your question to become an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a self-consistent set of classes which I can compile without any missing dependencies and then run the test against it, I cannot prove to you that I am right. Neither can you. Let code speak, speculation leads to nothing. The truth is in the code, so why won't you share it? There are no package or class names, missing methods etc.